# jquery onchange select value has a period on it

Tags: jquery

I have a select field like so.

```
<select id="v_bl_title" name="v_bl_title">
<option selected="" value="Mr.">Mr.</option>
<option value="Mrs.">Mrs.</option>
<option value="Ms.">Ms.</option>
<option value="Miss.">Miss</option>
<option value="">None</option>
</select>

$('#v_bl_title').bind('change',function(){
    var v_bl_title = $(this).val();
    $(#v_sh_title option[value=' + v_bl_title + ']').attr('selected', 'selected');
});
```

I am trying to copy the value over, but I cant get it to work with the period in the value.

I get the error 
uncaught exception: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [value=Ms.]

Is there a way to fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $('#v_bl_title').bind('change',function(){
    var v_bl_title = $(this).val();
     $("#v_sh_title option[value='" + v_bl_title + "']").attr('selected', 'selected');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/UGbm4/2/

or you can simply use `val`

```
$('#v_bl_title').bind('change',function(){
    var v_bl_title = $(this).val();
     $("#v_sh_title").val(v_bl_title);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/UGbm4/

Answer (score 0):

Yep, use quotation marks: `[value="Ms."]` I.e.:

```
  $('#v_bl_title').bind('change',function(){
    var v_bl_title = $(this).val();
    $('#v_sh_title option[value="' + v_bl_title + '"]').attr('selected', 'selected');
  });               // here ----^     and here ----^
```